# Why does this Fibonacci number function return infinity for the 4000th value?

Tags: javascript, fibonacci

Consider:

```
function fibo() {
    var first, second, add;
    for(var i=0; i<4000; i++) {
        if(i === 0) {
            first = 1;
            second = 2;
        }
        add = first + second;
        first = second;
        second = add;
    }
    alert(add);
}

fibo();
```

It is not working and shows infinity. Why?

Comment: Because the 4000th Fibonacci number is far to large for JavaScript to handle?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simple: because it's too big.

The 300th term is 222232244629420445529739893461909967206666939096499764990979600, so you might imagine how big the 4000th is. You can't hold such value in a JavaScript variable.

If you really want to calculate it, use an arbitrary precision library, and maybe something other than JavaScript if you want to calculate it fast.

Check [GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library - GMP](http://gmplib.org/). Nice to use with C, and it even has [special Fibonacci functions](http://gmplib.org/manual/Fibonacci-Numbers-Algorithm.html).

---

Here's a little C program to do the job:

```
#include <gmp.h>

int main()
{
    mpz_t num;
    mpz_init(num);

    mpz_fib_ui(num, 4000);
    gmp_printf("%Zd\n", num);

    return 0;
}
```

Compile with:

```
cc fib.c -lgmp
```

And run :-)

```
time ./a.out
39909473435004422792081248094960912600792570982820257852628876326523051818641373433549136769424132442293969306537520118273879628025443235370362250955435654171592897966790864814458223141914272590897468472180370639695334449662650312874735560926298246249404168309064214351044459077749425236777660809226095151852052781352975449482565838369809183771787439660825140502824343131911711296392457138867486593923544177893735428602238212249156564631452507658603400012003685322984838488962351492632577755354452904049241294565662519417235020049873873878602731379207893212335423484873469083054556329894167262818692599815209582517277965059068235543139459375028276851221435815957374273143824422909416395375178739268544368126894240979135322176080374780998010657710775625856041594078495411724236560242597759185543824798332467919613598667003025993715274875

real    0m0.005s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.002s
```

Comment: php's bcmath could handle an operation like that. Are you computing the value for something like Project Euler?

Comment: `perl -M'Math::BigInt lib=>GMP' -E 'my $a = Math::BigInt->new(0); my $b = Math::BigInt->new(1); for (3..4000) { $c = $a + $b; $a = $b; $b = $c } say $c'` :-P

Comment: @weblearner check my updated answer. Such a stupid time to calculate it (sorry for the wording).

Comment: @derobert I do love Perl, but check my C example and the time output :-)

Comment: @sidyll: Yes, it's a fair bit faster—but of course it should be, as you're using the GMP Fibonacci functions, which have much better ways of computing the answer than iterating the sequence. Amazingly, the perl one runs in only 0.085s here. Assumably the perl one would be just as fast if it Math::GMP->fibonacci; but that'd lose the illustrative power of doing the calculation. (Testing it, it is; interesting, GMP counts term # differently than I did)

Comment: @derobert What a fantastic machine you have! Your program runs in 0.495s here (old Core2Duo, 2GHz, maybe the C program runs in 0.000s for you :-) yet it's really fast for such calculation. And sure, the internal functions are much faster. By the way, I didn't know about the formulas described in the functions page (the link I posted in the answer).

Comment: @sidyll: This is a Core i7 930. Time for the C version shows 0.001s here. Which is faster than the perl `Math::GMP::fibonacci` one by .12 seconds, which is entirely the time it takes perl to load that module. (To be fair, it took 0.034s for `gcc -lgmp test.c -o test`, so perl loads the module faster than the C code compiles, unsurprisingly)

Comment: This answer should not be accepted. It has a false statement that JS can't deal with those large numbers. Several answers below present proper solutions to the problem. You can actually calculate larger numbers in a few ms in the SO snippet fcs

Answer (score 12):

Just for the sake of completeness, here is a pure JavaScript solution.  It uses a couple of libraries.

You will need **[biginteger](http://silentmatt.com/biginteger/)** and **[sloth](https://github.com/rfw/sloth.js)**.  The solution also requires [JavaScript 1.7 Generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators).

```
var window = {};
load('biginteger.js');
load('sloth.js');
var sloth = window.sloth;


function fibonacci(){
  var fn1 = new BigInteger(1);
  var fn2 = new BigInteger(1);

  while (1){
    var current = fn2;
    fn2 = fn1;
    fn1 = fn1.add(current);
    yield current;
  }
}

var iter = sloth.iter(fibonacci());
var some = sloth.ify(iter).take(4000).force();
print(some[299]);
print(some[3999]);
```

The code is a little eccentric (the use of load() and window), because I wanted to test it in [Rhino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhino_%28JavaScript_engine%29), without adding [npm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Npm_(software)) support.  If that confuses you, just pretend you're seeing a require() call :)

Comment: The link to sloth on github doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

A simpler solution: Just store numbers in arrays, one digit per element, and perform addition like you did in elementary school - "in columns". It goes like this:

```
function add(a, b) {
    while (a.length < b.length) a.unshift(0);
    while (a.length > b.length) b.unshift(0);
    var carry = 0, sum = []
    for (var i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var s = a[i] + b[i] + carry;
        if (s >= 10) {
            s = s - 10;
            carry = 1;
        } else {
            carry = 0;
        }
        sum.unshift(s);
    }
    if (carry)
        sum.unshift(carry);
    return sum;
}
```

And the Fibonacci function is like this:

```
function fib(n) {
    var f1 = [0];
    var f2 = [1];

    while (n--) {
        var f3 = add(f1, f2)
        f1 = f2;
        f2 = f3;
    }
    return f1.join("");
}
```

It seems totally ineffective, but it only takes fractions of a second to get `fib(4000)` on a 2.3 GHz [MacBook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro).

Answer (score 2):

Because `Number.MAX_VALUE + Number.MAX_VALUE === Infinity`

The issue is that `sum` exceeds JavaScript's capabilities for storing numeric values.

Answer (score 2):

#### Call

`fibonacci(4000)`

#### Result (836 digits)

39909473435004422792081248094960912600792570982820257852628876326523051818641373433549136769424132442293969306537520118273879628025443235370362250955435654171592897966790864814458223141914272590897468472180370639695334449662650312874735560926298246249404168309064214351044459077749425236777660809226095151852052781352975449482565838369809183771787439660825140502824343131911711296392457138867486593923544177893735428602238212249156564631452507658603400012003685322984838488962351492632577755354452904049241294565662519417235020049873873878602731379207893212335423484873469083054556329894167262818692599815209582517277965059068235543139459375028276851221435815957374273143824422909416395375178739268544368126894240979135322176080374780998010657710775625856041594078495411724236560242597759185543824798332467919613598667003025993715274875

#### Code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JavaScript Big Integers</title>

    <style>
        body{margin: 0 1em;width: auto;font-size: 125%}
        p{max-width: 800px;margin: 1ex 1em;}
        div{margin: 1em;}
        input, textarea, label{
            font-size: 1em;line-height: 1.2;font-family: arial, sans-serif;
            font-weight: 600;padding: 0 2px;
        }
        textarea{
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
            width: 90%;
            border: 2px ridge silver;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 5;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            height: 500px;
        }
        #fibInp{text-align: right;}
        #calcfibBtn, #stopFibBtn{color:navy;cursor:pointer}
        #calcfibBtn:focus, #stopFibBtn:focus, #calcfibBtn:hover, #stopFibBtn:hover{color:red}
    </style>

    <script>
        // Utilities
        // Internet Explorer version (if any) determines the initial loop size
        /*@cc_on
            @if(@_jscript_version > 5.5){
                navigator.IEmod =
                  document.documentMode ? document.documentMode :
                  window.XMLHttpRequest ? 7 : 6;
            }
            @end
        @*/

        function mr(hoo){
            if(hoo){
                if(typeof hoo == 'string')
                    return document.getElementById(hoo);
                if(hoo.nodeType === 1)
                    return hoo;
            }
            return null;
        }
        if(!Array.prototype.map){
            Array.prototype.map = function(fun, scope){
                var L = this.length, A = Array(this.length), i = 0, val;
                if(typeof fun == 'function'){
                    while(i < L){
                        if(i in this){
                            A[i] = fun.call(scope, this[i], i, this);
                        }
                        ++i;
                    }
                    return A;
                }
            }
        }

        // Big Integer Object
        function BigInt(n, sign){
            if(this.constructor != BigInt){
                if(n.constructor == BigInt)
                    return n;
                n = n.toString();
                if(/^\d+$/.test(n)){
                    var digits = n.split('').map(Number);
                    return new BigInt(digits.reverse(), sign);
                }
                else{
                    throw Error('base 10 integer input only');
                }
            }
            while(n.length && !n[n.length - 1]){
                --n.length;
            }
            this.digits = n;
            this.length = n.length;
            if(sign == -1)
                this.sign = sign;
        }

        BigInt.prototype.toString = function(){
            var s = this.digits.slice().reverse().join('');
            if(this.sign == -1)
                s = '-' + s;
            return s;
        }

        BigInt.prototype.plus = function(n){
            n = BigInt(n);
            var n1 = this.digits, n2 = n.digits,
            len1 = n1.length, len2 = n2.length,
            hoo = Array(Math.max(len1, len2) + 1),
            size = Math.min(len1, len2), temp = 0, dig;
            for(var i=0; i<size; i++){
                dig = n1[i] + n2[i] + temp;
                hoo[i] = dig%10;
                temp = (dig/10)|0;
            }
            if(len2 > len1){
                n1 = n2;
                len1 = len2;
            }
            for(var i= ize; temp && i<len1; i++){
                dig = n1[i] + temp;
                hoo[i] = dig%10;
                temp = (dig/10)|0;
            }
            if(temp)
                hoo[i] = temp;
            while(i < len1){
                hoo[i] = n1[i];
                ++i;
            }
            return new BigInt(hoo);
        }

        // Math.fibonacci methods
        Math.fibonacci = function(n){
            var n1 = 0, n2 = 1, t = 1, fib = [], i = 0;
            var limit = 9007199254740992;
            while(n1 < limit){
                fib[i++] = n1;
                if(i== n)
                    return fib;
                n2 = t;
                t = n1 + n2;
                n1 = n2;
            }
            if(n){
                t = fib.pop(), n1 = fib.pop(), i = fib.length;
                while(i < n){
                    fib[i++] = n1;
                    n2 = BigInt(t);
                    t = n2.plus(n1);
                    n1 = n2.toString();
                }
            }
            return fib;
        }

        Math.nthFibonacci = function(n, ret){
            var fibs = [0, 1], i = 78;
            while(n && --i){
                fibs[2] = fibs[0] + fibs[1];
                fibs.shift();
                n--;
            }
            if(n){
                fibs = [BigInt(fibs[0]), BigInt(fibs[1])];
                while(n--){
                    fibs[2] = fibs[0].plus(fibs[1]);
                    fibs.shift();
                }
            }
            return ret ? fibs : fibs[0];
        }

        // Demonstration code
        Fib={
            clear: function(){
                mr('yw_fib_tex').value = '';
                Fib.wait = false;
                mr('fibInp').value = '';
            },
            counter: 1,
            demo: function(){
                mr('calcfibBtn').onclick = Fib.getFib;
                mr('stopFibBtn').onclick = Fib.quitFib;
                mr('fibInp').onkeypress = Fib.keycheck;
                mr('fibInp').focus();
            },
            discomma: !!window.opera,
            getFib: function(){
                mr('yw_fib_tex').value = '';
                var d, c, n = mr('fibInp').value;
                n = parseInt(mr('fibInp').value);
                if(!n || n<2){
                    mr('fibInp').value = '';
                    mr('fibInp').focus();
                    return true;
                }
                if(n <= 1100){
                    d = Math.nthFibonacci(n).toString();
                    var fibs = ['', n, d.length, d];
                    Fib.report(fibs);
                    return true;
                }
                if(n > 10000){
                    d = Fib;
                    c = d.counter;
                    if(c > 2000){
                        Fib.reach(d.low, d.high, n, c, Fib.report);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                d = Math.nthFibonacci(1000, 1);
                Fib.reach(d[0], d[1], n, 1000, Fib.report);
                return true;
            },
            high: 1,
            keycheck: function(e){
                e = e || window.event;
                var k = e.charCode || e.keyCode;
                if(k == 13)
                    Fib.getFib();
                return true;
            },
            low: 0,
            quitFib: function(){
                Fib.wait = true;
                mr('yw_fib_tex').focus();
            },
            reach: function(n1, n2, n, i, cb){
                var d, q, who, mf = Fib, F = Fib.reach;
                if(F.time === undefined){
                    F.top = n;
                    F.count = i+1;
                    F.time = new Date().getTime();
                    F.cb = cb;
                    F.tik = false;
                }
                q = n2.toString().length;
                who = mr('yw_fib_tex');
                if(who){
                    if(q < 2100)
                        who.value = n2;
                    else
                        who.value = q + ' digits...thinking...';
                }
                if(q > 20000)
                    q = q > 100000 ? 10 : 20;
                else
                    if(q > 5000)
                        q = q > 10000 ? 50 : 100;
                else
                    q = q > 1000 ? 200 : 1000;
                if(navigator.IEmod) q /= 4;
                q = Math.min(q, F.top-F.count);
                while(q > 0){
                    d = BigInt(n1).plus(n2);
                    F.count++;
                    n1 = n2;
                    n2 = d;
                    --q;
                }
                if(F.count >= F.top || Fib.wait){
                    var t = (new Date()-F.time)/1000;
                    d = d.toString();
                    var fibs = [t, F.count, d.length, d, n1];
                    F.time = undefined;
                    if(typeof F.cb == 'function')
                        return F.cb(fibs);
                }
                else{
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        F(n1, d)
                    },
                    0);
                }
            },
            report: function(fb){
                var mf = Fib, s, fibz, f1 = fb[1], t = fb[0] || '', fN = fb[3];
                if(t){
                    t += mf.time;
                    if(mf.wait)
                        Fib.time += t;
                    else
                        Fib.time = 0;
                    t = t.toFixed(3) + ' seconds to calculate ';
                }
                fibz = t + 'fibonacci(' + f1 + ') [' + fb[2] + ' digits]';
                if(fb[4] && fN > mf.counter){
                    mf.counter = f1;
                    mf.low = fb[4];
                    mf.high = fN;
                }
                fN = fN.toString();
                if(window.opera){
                    fN = fN.replace(/(\d{10})/g, '$1 ');
                }
                fibz = fibz + '\n\n' + fN;
                mr('yw_fib_tex').value = fibz;
                Fib.wait = false;
                mr('yw_fib_tex').focus();
                return true;
            },
            time: 0,
            wait: false
        }
        window.onload = function(){
            Fib.demo();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h2 id="yw_fib_head">Fibonacci numbers in javascript</h2>
    <p>
    This is a demonstration of Big Integer Math
    in Javascript, handling numbers of arbitrary
    precision.
    The time it takes to calculate a large
    Fibonacci number depends on your
    computer and browser.</p>
    <div>
        <label>fibonacci#<input size="5" id="fibInp" type="text" value="1000"></label>
        <input type="button" id="calcfibBtn" value="Calculate">
        <input type="button" id="stopFibBtn" value="Stop">
        <br>
        <textarea readonly="readonly" id="yw_fib_tex">
        </textarea>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is just a light change in the function to get the maximum position possible to calculate by JavaScript.

Yes, the result will be different on each browser and architecture being used.

```
function fibo() {
    var first, second, add;
    for(var i=0; i<4000; i++) {
        if(i === 0) {
            first = 1;
            second = 2;
        }
        if(first + second > Number.MAX_VALUE) {
            console.debug(i, first, second);
            return;
        }
        add = first + second;
        first = second;
        second = add;
    }
    alert(add);
}
fibo();
```

The result is: `1473` `8.077637632156222e+307` `1.3069892237633987e+308`

Where 1473 is the maximum Fibonacci position possible to calculate with JavaScript.

The [BigInt](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-bigint-constructor) object can be used to increase the maximum integer value allowed by JavaScript, not limiting it to the computer architecture.

Comment: Just a heads up: The values wont be accurate due to floating point precision.

Comment: The link seems to be broken: *"This Serverless Function has crashed."*

Comment: The jsperf is gone. Unfortunately, that was a good way to test with multiple browsers, versions, and architectures, to get the different max values. Nowadays using BigInt will allow to get the 4000th position.

Answer (score 0):

[PubNub's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PubNub) [Ariya Hidayat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhantomJS) taught us this:

```
function fibo(n) {
    return Array.apply(0, Array(n)).reduce(function(x, y, z){return x.concat((z < 2) ? z : x[z-1] + x[z-2]); }, []);
}
```

Comment: surprised `x.concat` is used here, it's soooo much slower than `x.push(...); return x;`

Comment: I just measured it's more than **6x** slower to use concat instead of push! Despite the fact that the solution is not complete as you still have to add up the last two elements in the array.

Comment: Re *"PubNub's Ariya Hidayat taught us"*: What event? Can you provide some information about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WebWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) and [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) to calculate huge values of the Fibonacci sequence:

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var output = document.querySelector('#output');
var fulloutput = document.querySelector('#fulloutput');
var time = document.querySelector('#time');
var start, end;
var worker;

var createWorker = function () {
  if (worker) worker.terminate();
  var workerContent = "self.onmessage = " + workerFunction.toString();
  var blob = new Blob([workerContent], {type: 'application/javascript'});
  worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
  worker.onmessage = receive;
};

var workerFunction = function(event) {
  var total = BigInt(event.data);
  var fib = function(index) {
    var temp;
    var last = BigInt(0);
    var sum = BigInt(1);
    for (; index >= BigInt(2); index--) {
      if (index % BigInt(1000) === BigInt(0))
        self.postMessage({
          total: total,
          calculating: index
        });
      temp = last;
      last = sum;
      sum += temp;
    }
    return sum;
  };
  if (total > BigInt(0)) self.postMessage({done: fib(total)});
  else self.postMessage({error: 'Input error'});
};

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  if (!window.Worker ||
      !window.Blob   ||
      !window.URL    ||
      !window.BigInt) {
    output.textContent = 'Browser not supported';
  } else {
    start = performance.now();
    createWorker();
    output.textContent = 'Worker created, starting calculations';
    worker.postMessage(input.value);
    input.addEventListener('change', function () {
      createWorker();
      start = performance.now();
      output.textContent = 'Calculating';
      worker.postMessage(input.value);
    });
  }
});

var receive = function(event) {
  if (event.data.error) {
    output.textContent =  event.data.error;
  }
  if (event.data.calculating) {
    var total = BigInt(event.data.total);
    var index = BigInt(event.data.calculating);
    var progress = (BigInt(100) * (total - index) / total);
    output.textContent = 'Calculating ' + progress + '%';
  }
  if (event.data.done) {
    var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en', {
      notation: 'scientific'
    });
    output.textContent = formatter.format(event.data.done);
    fulloutput.textContent = event.data.done;
    end = performance.now();
    time.textContent = 'It took ' + ((end - start) / 1000) + ' seconds';
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
p, pre  {
  text-align: center;
  width: 80vw;
  white-space:normal;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<p>N: <input type="number" value="4000"></p>
<pre id="output"></pre>
<pre id="fulloutput"></pre>
<pre id="time"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

there is actually 1475 numbers before infinite. this number is 1.3069892237633987e+308.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.