# Max call stack exceeded

Tags: javascript

I understand what maximum call stack exceeded is. However, is there a workaround for this for my code? Furthermore, there will be a time where it eventually will stop looping, that is when position > counter1.

```
var a = 0;
var b = 1;
var c;
var counter1 = 1;
var position = 0;

window.onload = function() {
    var position = prompt("Please enter the position number.","0");
    calc1();
}

function calc1() {
    if(position <= counter1) {
    c = a+b;
        counter1++;
        calc2();
    }
    else {
    callResult();
    }
}

function calc2() {
    if(position <= counter1) {
    a = b+c;
    counter1++;
    calc3();
    }
    else {
    callResult();
    }
}

function calc3() {
    if(position <= counter1) {
        b = c+a;
    counter1++;
    calc1();
    }
    else {
    callResult();
    }
}

function callResult() {
    if (position %3 == 1) {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = a;
    }
    else if (position %3 == 2) {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = b;
   }
    else {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = c;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you *ever* figure out the code flow if this is how you indent your code?

Comment: This is not how I normally indent. Its usually 4 spaces, then the next indent is a tab. But for this website you need to have 4 spaces to show it's code, so I tried to minimized time wasted so I can get answers quickly. But if it does affect people, I'll change it now

Comment: So, you increment counter1 when position is <= counter1, but never change position, so the counter gets bigger and bigger and thereby keeps calling calc1 -> calc2 -> calc3  -> calc1? etc....

Comment: It stops when position > counter1.

Comment: and if it is always less, e.g. 0?

Comment: It actually never stops in this code as @doctorlove pointed out

Comment: @Simon I have not added that yet as there already is a problem now. But when this is solved I will add that. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should avoid recursion and use loop. Something like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var position = prompt("Please enter the position number.","0");
    maincalc();
}

function maincalc() {
    var subcalc = [ calc1, calc2, calc3 ];
    var calccount = 0;

    while(position <= counter1) {
        subcalc[ calccounter ]();
        calccounter = (calccounter +1) % 3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of position is given once and never changed.

You then check, `if(position <= counter1)` in each call `calc1`, `calc2`, `calc3` which call each other thus:

`calc1` -> `calc2` -> `calc3` -> `calc1` -> ...

This will clearly continue until you run out of stack space.

Perhaps if you increment `position` instead of `counter1` or keep calling while position is greater than the counter this problem will go away, 
i.e.

```
if(position > counter1)
```

You probably need to step back and think about what you are really trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my careless mistake. I actually wanted to increment counter1 and execute the code until counter1 is more than the position.

Answer (score 0):

as I understand you are calculating Fibonacci numbers sum?

see this [Javascript Fibonacci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331492/javascript-fibonacci) answer to learn how to do it much easier and without any recursive calls