# gettin NaN instead of a value in my array result

Tags: javascript, arrays, nan

I'm creating a function to do some calculus and the result will be displayed on the navigator console using `console.log` ,but I'm facing a problem with the `Array`  result which succeed on adding the first result to my main `Array` using `arr.push(result)` but the rest of the occurrence are displayed as `NaN`

this is the code :

```
function  Fibo() {
    var arr = [1, 2, 3];
    var result = 0;
    while(result < 4000000) {
          result = arr[arr.indexOf(arr.length)] + arr[arr.indexOf(arr.length - 1)];
          arr.push(result);
          console.log(arr);
          result = 0
    } 
}

Fibo();
```

This is the result :

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, NaN]
[1, 2, 3, 5, NaN, NaN]
[1, 2, 3, 5, NaN, NaN, NaN]
[1, 2, 3, 5, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN]
[1, 2, 3, 5, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN]
[1, 2, 3, 5, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN]
[1, 2, 3, 5, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN]
[1, 2, 3, 5, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN]
[1, 2, 3, 5, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN]
```

Comment: Summing `undefined` with a number or another `undefined` results `NaN`.

Comment: [Also good to know](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331492/javascript-fibonacci/8331546#8331546) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main issues:

1. indexOf isn't the right method to use. Following the code step-by-step...

   ```
   arr[arr.indexOf(arr.length)] + arr[arr.indexOf(arr.length - 1)]
   arr[arr.indexOf(3)] + arr[arr.indexOf(2)]
   arr[2] + arr[1]
   3 + 2
   5

   arr[arr.indexOf(arr.length)] + arr[arr.indexOf(arr.length - 1)];
   arr[arr.indexOf(4)] + arr[arr.indexOf(3)]
   arr[-1] + arr[2]
   undefined + 2
   NaN
   ```
2. Setting result to 0 at the end of the while-loop will cause the while-loop to run in an infinite loop! My guess is that you were clearing out variables, but be careful!

The below code fixes both issues (result is lower just as a sanity-check)

```
function Fibo() {
    var arr = [1, 2, 3];
    var result = 0;
    while(result < 400) {
          result = arr[arr.length-1] + arr[arr.length-2];
          if (isNaN(result)) { return }
          arr.push(result);
          console.log(arr);
    } 
}

Fibo();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you add the 5 to your array it breaks, Here's what's happeing.  Your array is now of length 4.
There is no 4 in your array so `arr.indexOf(arr.length)` is `-1`.
`arr[-1]` is `undefined`
`undefined -1` is `NaN`

Instead of using indexOf you just want to add the last 2 number in the list and ad that to the end.

```
function  Fibo() {
var arr = [1, 2];
var result = 0;
while(result < 100) {
      result = arr[arr.length -1] + arr[arr.length -2];
      arr.push(result);
      console.log(arr);
  }
}

Fibo();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a NaN check before your push

```
function  Fibo() {
    var arr = [1, 2, 3];
    var result = 0;
    while(result < 4000000) {
          result = arr[arr.indexOf(arr.length)] + arr[arr.indexOf(arr.length - 1)];
          if (isNaN(result)) { return }
          arr.push(result);
          console.log(arr);
          result = 0
    } 
}
```

Comment: It's good to do sanity checking on `result`, but there's something wrong with how `result` is being built in the first place

Comment: @ChrisForrence Yep, and you've nailed the issue in the second comment too : )

Answer (score 0):

On the second time around the loop, arr.length === 4. That's not an element of your array, so that's your first problem. You might want to use arr[arr.length - 1] instead.